# SharePoint Modern site - News webpart not editable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, modern-experience

All of a sudden my news webpart is uneditable.

Nothing has changed that I am able to detect.

We have a communication site with a bunch of subsites.

I created a news feature on a subsite and all of a sudden I am not able to see any editing options - Just the layout. I have tried different browsers, cleared cache, checked logs...I can't find a reason and I can't find a recommendation, advice or solution.

Any ideas welcome.

SP2019 on prem

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or 2019?

Comment: @garvon-77: are you able to edit the page itself?  Is the webpart aggregating from the sub-sites?  If so, try adding a new News webpart and configuring that and report back results.  If you are using #sharepoint-online : I am experiencing something kinda similar to you, but different - it appears to be a permissions issue for some of my users and the permissions for some users seem to be changing - without me or anyone else making the change.  The auditing & compliance section in O365 admin center shows no changes to permissions.  I have been juggling this issue for more than a week.

Comment: Yes - aggregating from subsite. I was able to set it up a few backs and no chance of getting the editing to open. I have attempted a new webpart with the same result - nothing.
I am able to get to the page / post settings with the defaults for the promoted pages. That does not help though. I have maximum Full Control permissions. Running SP2019 on premise. I found today that on the communication site I  was not able to edit that news web part either which was create about 8 months ago.